# Python Help .Join giving syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have been learning Python on Codecademy.com and transferred a project that worked on the site (Battle Ship for those who used the site) and now I'm getting a syntax error with part of my code. On the site it runs smoothly.

The problem is when I take a list of strings and use join on them to display the game board.

```
result = " ".join(row)
print result
```

It is giving the error on the print result. On the site, the code was one line but I broke it down to see what was giving the error. Currently I have python 3.3 installed. Could something have changed between the version of Python interpreters that may have cause this?

Comment: Codecademy says on the main Python page that they use `2.7.3` just for your information.

Comment: "Could something have changed [...]?". Read [What’s New In Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html).

Comment: Thanks for the input. This is only my third day of Python and I haven't done much with the interpreter, can I have both versions installed at once or would that cause problems

Comment: You can have both versions.  But stick with p3 for now until you learn more.  How to install both depends on whether you are using Windows, Mac or Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3.x, `print` is a function, so try:

```
result = " ".join(row)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following in python 2,

`print "%s." %" ".join(row)`

Alternatively, use the following in python 3,

`print(*row, sep=' ')`